# Ionic 2: Add URL Schemes automatically to the Whitelist for ios from config.xml

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I add the ios schemes in my Ionic 2/Cordova project in `config.xml` as follows:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
    <config-file parent="LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
      <array>
        <string>skype</string>
      </array>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

These will not appear under `platforms/ios/<appname>/<appname>-Info.plist`. I need to make the entries manually on Mac in the file `<appname>-Info.plist`! This isn't practical!

How can these entries be automatically included in the `<appname>-Info.plist` from `config.xml` of ionic 2 project?

thanks

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @Sagivf still not :/

Answer (score 4):

`config.xml` is the right place, however, you need to add the tag `edit-config` and arguments as follow:

```
<widget ...>
    <platform name="ios">
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="LSApplicationQueriesSchemes">
            <array>
                <string>skype</string>
            </array>
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually adding this in the config.xml is the wrong place. You need is to create a plugin that has the correct schemes in **plugin.xml**. Something like this - github.com/rjhilgefort/cordova-plugin-queries-schemes